# Transparent tab bar in react navigation without absolute positioning

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to create a transparent tab bar navigation. The only solution I have found so far is by absolute positioning which causes problems in screens as the content is being overlapped. Is there a way to make the bottom navigation transparent without absolute positioning?

The project uses react navigation 3.0.9

```
tabBarOptions: {
      // NOTE: Transparent bar
      indicatorStyle: {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      },
      tabStyle: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
        borderTopWidth: 0.5,
        borderTopColor: 'white',
        height: 70,
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
      },
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this?